# Bad_alloc Exception in function in C++

Tags: c++, function, exception

Hi I am new in C++ programming, I have a function that return `short*`

**My Function Code is**

This function executes thousands of time because of this bad_alloc at memory location in generated so can anyone tell me how to solve this.

**Code where getoneframe function call**

```
short *myData = NULL;
sock.SetCameraIP(m_destination_IP, m_destination_port);

m_startCamFlag = sock.StartCamera();
if (!m_startCamFlag)
{
    std::cout << "Unable to Start the Camera" << std::endl;
}

std::thread acquiringThread(callReceiveFunction, sock);
acquiringThread.detach();

while (flag)
{
    myData = sock.GetOneFrame();
    ImageShow(myData);
    Sleep(15);
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE))
    {
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function allocates dynamic memory in the line

```
short         *m_returnframeBuffer = new short[BYTE_PER_FRAME];
```

and returns the pointer to the calling function as

```
return m_returnframeBuffer;
```

It sounds like the calling function does not deallocate the memory, which causes `bad_alloc` to be thrown when the function is called thousands of times.

Make sure that the calling function deallocates the memory after it is done using it.

```
short* buffer = SomeCameraObject.GetOneFrame();

// Use buffer

// Deallocate memory.
delete [] buffer;
```

---

Update the `while` loop in the calling function to:

```
while (flag)
{
    myData = sock.GetOneFrame();
    ImageShow(myData);
    Sleep(15);
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE))
    {
        flag = false;
    }

    // Add this line
    delete [] myData;
}
```

Comment: @Mickey, exactly what I thought. Add `delete [] myData;` as the last statement of the `while` loop in the calling function.

Answer (score 1):

```
    while (m_bufferIndex1 != MAX_BYTE_PER_FRAME)
    {
        m_myChar1 = m_frameBuffer1[m_bufferIndex1++];
        m_myChar2 = m_frameBuffer1[m_bufferIndex1++];
        value = (m_myChar1 << 8) | m_myChar2;
        m_returnframeBuffer[m_bufferIndex2++] = value;
    }
```

`m_bufferIndex1` is getting incremented twice. So, if m_bufferIndex1 is `MAX_BYTE_PER_FRAME-1`, it will enter the loop and gets incremented twice and the while loop never breaks. Add another check there before incrementing second time